# Special character problem in J2ME

Tags: xml, java-me, special-characters, kxml2

I am reading unicode character from XML like `\u09A8\u09AC\u09AE`. I have used `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in the heading of XML. When I parsing xml from server using `KXML2` parser it makes every unicode character a string. If I convert it to character array it gives like :

Char 0: \

Char 1: u

Char 2: 0

Char 3: 9

Char 4: B

Char 5: E

How can I get my unicode character back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML `\u09A8` is **not** a Unicode character reference in XML!

There are only a few places that treat `\u` as the beginning of a Unicode escape, and they are mostly in the Java area.

In XML a hexidecimal Unicode escape would be `&#x09A8;` and a decimal one would be `&#2472;`.

In other words: You get the characters `\`, `u`, `0`, `9`, `B`, `E` back, because **that's what the XML contains**.

The **best** solution is to fix whatever *produces* this XML to use actual numeric entity references. Alternatively, you can manually replace the `\u` escapes with their corresponding characters, but then *only* your code will correctly interpret this non-standard XML.